# How to name a Class for container of resulted items of a clicked item?

Tags: class, arraylist

I have an item X that when clicked will be splitted into 1 or more items.

So I have an ArrayList that will be returning the items but I am not sure of how to name the class of that ArrayList.

the class will hold itemName and Count.

```
public class WhatNameShouldItBe
{
    public int itemId ...;
    public int itemCount ...;
}
ArrayList<WhatNameShouldItBe> resultItems;
```

PS: Sorry about the question title ... if you need more information let me know was not sure if anything else was needed to such a question.

Some names I was thinking about:

ExtractedItems but since it is not extracted yet doesnt sound right to me...
ResultedItems or ResultItems
ClickableItemsResult

It is a list of items that can be given to the user when they use a clickable item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English isn't my native language, but I'll give it a shot anyway : `SpawnedItem` ?

Comment: hi, thanks for the input the name indeed sounds appealing as when you click the item X it would spawn items Y thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a class describing something that has properties. Say it's a Widget. Each widget has an ID and a Count.

You then want a list of these Widgets. No problem, you make an ArrayList and name it something appropriate to what purpose the list serves:

```
public class Widget
{
    public int itemId ...;
    public int itemCount ...;
}
ArrayList<Widget> ClickedWidgets;
```

If the main purpose of the list is to differentiate those Widgets that were clicked on, then call it `ClickedWidgets` or something similar.

Remember, the most important thing about naming variables in programming is that it makes sense to you. (It also helps if others can figure it out later!)

Comment: thanks for the comment but widgets sounds out of context but i get the point here but the more i think about it the worst the name gets ehhehehe

Answer (score 0):

A little bit vague on the question, but perhaps "Fragments" would work.